# How to import from SQLite database?

Tags: sqlite, r

I have an SQLite database file exported from Scraperwiki with .sqlite file extension. How do I import it into R, presumably mapping the original database tables into separate data frames?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You could use the [RSQLite](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite/index.html) package.

Some example code to store the whole data in `data.frame`s:

```
library("RSQLite")

## connect to db
con <- dbConnect(drv=RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname="YOURSQLITEFILE")

## list all tables
tables <- dbListTables(con)

## exclude sqlite_sequence (contains table information)
tables <- tables[tables != "sqlite_sequence"]

lDataFrames <- vector("list", length=length(tables))

## create a data.frame for each table
for (i in seq(along=tables)) {
  lDataFrames[[i]] <- dbGetQuery(conn=con, statement=paste("SELECT * FROM '", tables[[i]], "'", sep=""))
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I seem to have a problem now w/ my SQLite export files, seeming broken as far as the import goes (I see the tables but lDataFrames shows NULL items... I need to go and do some tests I think.. Sqlite src is at https://scraperwiki.com/scrapers/export_sqlite/f1_timing/

Comment: @psychemedia Some of your table names contains "-". You have to quote the name of the table `SELECT * FROM 'TABLE-ONE'`. I updated my example code.

Comment: Thanks... just spotted that now myself... Doh!

Comment: you may wanna change `con <- dbConnect(drv="SQLite", dbname="YOURSQLITEFILE")` to `con <- dbConnect(drv=SQLite(), dbname="YOURSQLITEFILE")`

Comment: furthermore, the for loop you wrote there does not store the data as `data.frames` but as a large list. Thats enough (under the for i in seq line) `lDataFrames[[i]]<- data.frame(dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM '", tables[[i]))`

Comment: @Chrissl: Mh, seems fine for me: `class(dbGetQuery(conn=con, statement=paste("SELECT * FROM '", tables[[1]], "'", sep="")))` shows `data.frame`

Comment: did not work for me, but then I was not in a loop neither. Just suggesting :)

Comment: Remember to call `dbDisconnect()` when you finish working with a connection

Answer (score 6):

To anyone else that comes across this post, a nice way to do the loop from the top answer using the purr library is:

```
lDataFrames <- map(tables, ~{
  dbGetQuery(conn=con, statement=paste("SELECT * FROM '", .x, "'", sep=""))
})
```

Also means you don't have to do:

```
lDataFrames <- vector("list", length=length(tables))
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting together sgibb's and primaj's answers, naming tables, and adding facility to retrieve all tables or a specific table:

```
getDatabaseTables <- function(dbname="YOURSQLITEFILE", tableName=NULL){
  library("RSQLite")
  con <- dbConnect(drv=RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname=dbname) # connect to db
  tables <- dbListTables(con) # list all table names

  if (is.null(tableName)){
    # get all tables
    lDataFrames <- map(tables, ~{ dbGetQuery(conn=con, statement=paste("SELECT * FROM '", .x, "'", sep="")) })
    # name tables
    names(lDataFrames) <- tables
    return (lDataFrames)
  }
  else{
    # get specific table
    return(dbGetQuery(conn=con, statement=paste("SELECT * FROM '", tableName, "'", sep="")))
  }
}

# get all tables
lDataFrames <- getDatabaseTables(dbname="YOURSQLITEFILE")

# get specific table
df <- getDatabaseTables(dbname="YOURSQLITEFILE", tableName="YOURTABLE")
```